# power series representation theorem help

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

I am having trouble trying to understand a step in this theorem. Basically how do they justify $\int_{1}^{1+x} \frac{(1-t)^n}{t} dt\leq \int_{1}^{1+x} (t-1)^n dt$. I tried solving the left side integral but it is pretty ugly. I'm sure there is something obvious i'm not seeing. Clarifying this step will be great thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x) \leq g(x)$ on $[a,b]$ for all $x$, then $\int_a^b f(t) dt \leq \int_a^b g(t) dt$. In this case, $\frac{(1 - t)^n}{t} \leq (t - 1)^n$ on $[1, 1 + x]$ since $t \geq 1$ on this interval.

Comment: Thank you so much I forgot about that theorem.